# Change how multiple values in one cell are displayed

Tags: ms-access

I have a table person (id omitted):

```
first name | last name
----------------------
peter      | parker
mary jane  | watson
J Jonah    | Jameson
```

And I have a table course:

```
course name | attendees
------------------------------
Chemistry   | peter; J Jonah
Photography | peter; mary jane
```

I used the "Nachschlage-Assistent" (sorry for german, I don't know the original term) to connect the attendees-column to store multiple persons. Now Id like to change, how the Persons are displayed in this cells, preferably in a report:

```
course name | attendees
-------------------------------------------
Chemistry   | Peter Parker, J Jonah Johnson
Photography | Peter Parker, Mary Jane Watson
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you used was "Lookup Wizard" to create a lookup field in table. Then the field was set to allow multiple values. This is a multi-value field (MVF). Advise not to build lookup fields in table nor to use multi-value field.

If attendees field is actually saving ID (as it should) and displaying first name, modify combobox RowSource property SQL statement to:

`SELECT ID, StrConv([first name] & " " & [last name], 3) AS FullName FROM person;`

StrConv() function will convert text to proper case so first letter of each word is capitalized and others are not. This is not a perfect solution because "mcdonald" will become "Mcdonald" instead of "McDonald" and "von der heide" will be "Von Der Heide" instead of "von der Heide". For more info review http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/action-queries/proper-case/index.htm

Also advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: While I did not actually need the StrConv-Function, your answer guided me to how I can change the SQL for a field. Thank you so much! Just by the way, while I probably will still use mvf and lookup fields, because it works fine in my case, I am interested, why I should not use them. Can you recommend a link?

Comment: Review http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm. No 7 applies to MVF and MVF are just more complicated to work with in some data manipulation processes. Keep in mind Attachment type field is an MVF, in case you also use those. Most experienced developers will not use these Access-exclusive features.